# scala.Some cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map Exception

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm new to scala,

```
val data = Map("test" -> data1, 
               "cat" -> None, 
               "myList" -> Map("test2" -> data2, "test3" -> data3))

val output = data.map(x => 
      if (x._2.isInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]) (x._1 -> Some(x._2)) 
      else x)

Map(test -> data1, 
    cat -> None, 
    myList -> Some(Map(test2 -> data2, test3 -> data3)))

val valueToFieldMapping = output(fieldName).get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]]
```

I'm getting

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Some cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map
```

exception please help me if anyone has an idea about this. Thanks

Comment: Your code confuses me a bit. Like the `Map` declared at line 9 isn't assigned to any `val`... is it ever used? Also, you seem to call a function `output` with input `fieldName`... where is the function defined? What's `fieldName`?

One last thing... you data is a `Map` from `String` to `Any`... any particular reason to have `Any`? It can cause lots of headaches and cast exceptions later.

Comment: Cast and `Any` are generally symptoms of something wrong before

Comment: Please provide full code, Like what are the values of all the parameters.

Comment: This code does not compile because the last line is calling `get` on a value of type `Any`. Perhaps you have missed something out when you simplified it for this question?

Comment: @mfirry `output` is a `Map` not a function, `output(fieldValue)` is extracting a value from the `Map` using the key `fieldValue`.

Comment: What is the field name?

Comment: You're totally right @Tim ... not sure how I assumed that it was a function call. Cheers!

Comment: what you actually want to do can you explain?

Comment: @All,Thanks for immediate response on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, let's clean up the definition of `output` by using `mapValues`:

```
val output = data.mapValues(x =>
  if (x.isInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]) Some(x)
  else x)
```

Then do this

```
val valueToFieldMapping = output(fieldName).asInstanceOf[Option[Map[String, String]]].get
```

You can't call `get` on the `Some` you generate when creating `output` because the compile doesn't know it is an `Option` yet.

Having said all that, the comments are right in saying that using `Any` and `asInstanceOf` is really ugly so you need to find a better way of expressing whatever it is you are trying to do. At the very least, use `match` rather than `asInstanceOf` so that you can implement the error case if the object is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line you don't have .get property on instance of Object.
you don't need .get if you want to use .get method then do output.get(fieldName)

```
val valueToFieldMapping = output(fieldName).get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]]
```

`output.get(fieldName)` gives you the `Option[Object]` and you are trying to convert object into the instance of the `Map[String, String]`

there is no implicit conversion from Option to map so that's the reason you are getting the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Some cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map
```

or you can do like this:

```
val valueToFieldMapping: Option[Map[String, String]] = output.get(fieldName).asInstanceOf[Option[Map[String, String]]]
```

Comment: Why does `output(fieldName).get` give `Option[Object]`? The type of `output` is `Map[String, Any]` so `output(fieldName)` is `Any` (or an exception) and `Any` doesn't have a `get` method. Perhaps you are thinking of `output.get(fieldName)` which returns `Option[Any]`?

Comment: yeah i just miss typed i ment output.get(fieldName) which gives Option[Object] because the type of output: Map[String, Object]